# Where is my .vmc config file for Virtual PC

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Where does Virtual PC stores the .vmc files ? I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is in the **My Virtual Machines** folder under **My Documents**, but you can specify something else on creation:

[image]