# VMC parameter file (XML) path

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc, parameters

I'm trying to find the VMC XML parameter file. 
Does anyone know where it is located? 
Or name of the parameter file (.xml)  ?

For example:

```
c:\user\***\windows\virtualpc\parameter.xml
```

Virtual PC on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Usually stored in the same dir as the .vhds (which you can select when you create the vm).

For Windows 7 try looking in

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Virtual Machines\
```

where `xxxxx` is your username.

For Windows XP [it will be in the My Virtual Machines folder under My Documents](https://superuser.com/questions/77144/where-is-my-vmc-config-file-for-virtual-pc?rq=1).

Comment: it's no there , im searching a .xml file, here just find vmcx , thanks !

Comment: the `.vmcx` file is in XML format.  That's the only one I've got on my machine.